# Python pbkdf2_hmac vs JavaScript crypto.pbkdf2Sync inconsistent hash

Tags: python, node.js, flask, cryptography, hashlib

I'm migrating a Flask application to Node. I want to generate the same password hashes in Node as I do in Python. However, the hashes don't match. Why are the results different?

```python
import hashlib, binascii    

salt = 'aa'     
input_pwd = '1'   
fromHex_salt = binascii.a2b_hex(salt)    
dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha1', input_pwd.encode('utf-8'), fromHex_salt, 1000, dklen=32)
python_result = binascii.hexlify(dk).decode('utf-8')
```

```javascript
const crypto = require('crypto');
const salt = 'aa';
const input_pwd = '1';
const js_result = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(input_pwd, salt, 1000, 32, 'sha1').toString('hex');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to decode your salt from Hex in node.js:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const salt = 'aa';
const input_pwd = '1';
console.log(crypto.pbkdf2Sync(input_pwd, new Buffer(salt, 'hex'), 1000, 32, 'sha1').toString('hex'));
```